# Storing test data in OpenCv4Android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

Is there any way to save test data in OpenCv4Android(in java not native) like FileStorage class in OpenCv in C++ ?

Comment: What can you say about my answer? If it's correct than why don't you accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at [official OpenCV java documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/) (version 2.4.3.2) I didn't find any alternatives to c++ `FileStorage`. So you should save and read the data by yourself or use native code.